# Plotting subplots with secondary continuous y-axis across all subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have a numpy arrays of temperature, wind speed, heat flux etc. Each of these arrays is assigned to its own subplot. The snow depth I would like to be plotted on the combined area of the subplots. As if the second y-axis is of one plot.

In the attached image is what I would like to create [image: example plot]. One can see the snow depth is on the secondary y-axis.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html

Comment: Have you tried anything?  People are more willing to help you fix broken code, than write code for you wholesale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `twinx()` to create a second y-axis that shares the same x-axis

```
ax1 = axes()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

x = np.arange(100)
y1 = np.random.rand(100)
y2 = np.random.rand(100)

ax1.plot(x,y1,'-r')
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2.fill_between(x,0,y2,color='b',alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_ylim(0,2)

ax1.set_ylabel('Red')
ax2.set_ylabel('Blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I am actually looking for overlapping two axis on the left y-axis and having a third one on the right side. This means there are 3 curve sharing the same x-axis on the same graph. Can twinx add multiple dataset on the y-axis.

Comment: Sorry, your original question wasn't very clear. The example that @tcaswell linked to describes exactly what you're looking for.